Javascript form.submit() doesn't trigger form submission while onSubmit event
const apiRedirectUrl = redirectUrl + '&sessionToken=' + response.sessionToken;    const form = document.createElement('form');    form.method = 'POST';    form.action = apiRedirectUrl;    document.body.appendChild(form);    console.log('calling submit');form.submit(); document.body.removeChild(form);
I want to submit the dynamic form while onSubmit.
based on the action want to redirect.`

Hey Mayank, welcome! Please take the time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, this will give you a good starting point on the editing that you need to to in order to make this question answerable.
